# RFC 1939 на русском языке

Tags: pop3, rfc

Всем доброго времени суток.

Не могу найти в интернет полное описание pop3 протокола на русском языке, может кто знает, где можно взять?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 1939 — Протокол POP3](http://rfc2.ru/1939.rfc)